# Getting an error "Invalid endpoint:" while running aws ec2 describe-regions --output table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

While running this command in Mac terminal I am getting this error:

Command:

```
aws ec2 describe-regions --output table
```

Error:

```
Invalid endpoint: https://ec2.Asia Pacific (Sydney).amazonaws.com
```

My default region is: Asia Pacific (Sydney)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say your aws region is set to `Asia Pacific (Sydney)` when it should be `ap-southeast-2`.

Run `aws configure` again to fix it, or edit your `~/.aws/config` file with the correct value.

Comment: This was not working too so, I assigned an AdminAcess policy to the user and it worked.